# Get the index of the object clicked on

Tags: javascript

Here is my code that I use to get data from the api, I need its index to be output to the console by clicking on the text

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '<api_key>',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
};

const a1 = document.querySelector('.player-artist');

async function getResponse() {
  
  let response = await fetch('https://shazam-core.p.rapidapi.com/v1/charts/world', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
  
  response.forEach(function (item, i) {
    let title = item.title
    a1.innerHTML += `
      <li class="post">
        ${title}
        <img src="${response[i].images.background}" width="300">
      </li>
    `
  })
}
  
getResponse()
```

I was able to implement this inside the function, but it output all the indexes to me at once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding an event listener to each `post` item it might be easier to add one to the containing element (`.list`), and use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to catch events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM.

For brevity I've taken a couple of objects from the API response and hard-coded them into this answer.

```js
// Grab the list, and attach an event listener to it
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
list.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// When `list` catches an event, it finds the nearest
// .post item, extracts its index, and then logs it
function handleClick(e) {
  const post = e.target.closest('.post');
  const { index } = post.dataset;
  console.log(`index: ${index}`);
}

async function getResponse() {
  
  const data=[{layout:"5",type:"MUSIC",key:"53510886",title:"Bloody Mary",subtitle:"Lady Gaga",share:{subject:"Bloody Mary - Lady Gaga",text:"I used Shazam to discover Bloody Mary by Lady Gaga.",href:"https://www.shazam.com/track/53510886/bloody-mary",image:"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/65/1b/f6/651bf621-fcf2-e3ba-4ef4-22645f26e0a0/11UMGIM12477.rgb.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",twitter:"I used @Shazam to discover Bloody Mary by Lady Gaga.",html:"https://www.shazam.com/snippets/email-share/53510886?lang=en&country=GB",avatar:"https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music122/v4/2c/7d/5e/2c7d5ec0-bad6-5fb6-08f2-ccfd94aa2985/pr_source.png/800x800cc.jpg",snapchat:"https://www.shazam.com/partner/sc/track/53510886"},images:{background:"https://is2-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music122/v4/2c/7d/5e/2c7d5ec0-bad6-5fb6-08f2-ccfd94aa2985/pr_source.png/800x800cc.jpg",coverart:"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/65/1b/f6/651bf621-fcf2-e3ba-4ef4-22645f26e0a0/11UMGIM12477.rgb.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",coverarthq:"https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/65/1b/f6/651bf621-fcf2-e3ba-4ef4-22645f26e0a0/11UMGIM12477.rgb.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",joecolor:"b:040809p:f3f2eds:c9c9c9t:c3c3c0q:a1a2a2"},hub:{type:"APPLEMUSIC",image:"https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/applemusic.png",actions:[{name:"apple",type:"applemusicplay",id:"1440824272"},{name:"apple",type:"uri",uri:"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview122/v4/c7/b0/df/c7b0dfe8-e1dc-1bda-88b0-0dc9b67e1b1b/mzaf_15572490037611837314.plus.aac.ep.m4a"}],options:[{caption:"OPEN",actions:[{name:"hub:applemusic:deeplink",type:"applemusicopen",uri:"https://music.apple.com/gb/album/bloody-mary/1440824019?i=1440824272&mttnagencyid=s2n&mttnsiteid=125115&mttn3pid=Apple-Shazam&mttnsub1=Shazam_web&mttnsub2=5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973&itscg=30201&app=music&itsct=Shazam_web"},{name:"hub:applemusic:deeplink",type:"uri",uri:"https://music.apple.com/gb/album/bloody-mary/1440824019?i=1440824272&mttnagencyid=s2n&mttnsiteid=125115&mttn3pid=Apple-Shazam&mttnsub1=Shazam_web&mttnsub2=5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973&itscg=30201&app=music&itsct=Shazam_web"}],beacondata:{type:"open",providername:"applemusic"},image:"https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/overflow-open-option.png",type:"open",listcaption:"Open in Apple Music",overflowimage:"https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/applemusic-overflow.png",colouroverflowimage:!1,providername:"applemusic"}],explicit:!1,displayname:"APPLE MUSIC"},artists:[{alias:"lady-gaga",id:"42",adamid:"277293880"}],url:"https://www.shazam.com/track/53510886/bloody-mary",highlightsurls:{},properties:{}},{layout:"5",type:"MUSIC",key:"636972694",title:"The Astronaut",subtitle:"JIN",share:{subject:"The Astronaut - JIN",text:"I used Shazam to discover The Astronaut by JIN.",href:"https://www.shazam.com/track/636972694/the-astronaut",image:"https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music122/v4/1b/38/ea/1b38eacd-158d-5040-8887-2786d2a641bc/192641874338_Cover.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",twitter:"I used @Shazam to discover The Astronaut by JIN.",html:"https://www.shazam.com/snippets/email-share/636972694?lang=en&country=GB",avatar:"https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/AMCArtistImages112/v4/a1/b7/ca/a1b7ca45-84c6-1939-70cb-fdfb79c23b68/c6967405-5d2d-4e64-91ec-be857bb9b0b6_ami-identity-e3de1066dd9a89fa6fadb60b1a50fdd9-2022-10-24T04-08-49.135Z_cropped.png/800x800cc.jpg",snapchat:"https://www.shazam.com/partner/sc/track/636972694"},images:{background:"https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/AMCArtistImages112/v4/a1/b7/ca/a1b7ca45-84c6-1939-70cb-fdfb79c23b68/c6967405-5d2d-4e64-91ec-be857bb9b0b6_ami-identity-e3de1066dd9a89fa6fadb60b1a50fdd9-2022-10-24T04-08-49.135Z_cropped.png/800x800cc.jpg",coverart:"https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music122/v4/1b/38/ea/1b38eacd-158d-5040-8887-2786d2a641bc/192641874338_Cover.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",coverarthq:"https://is5-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music122/v4/1b/38/ea/1b38eacd-158d-5040-8887-2786d2a641bc/192641874338_Cover.jpg/400x400cc.jpg",joecolor:"b:000000p:fdfdfds:2ffdcbt:cacacaq:25caa3"},hub:{type:"APPLEMUSIC",image:"https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/applemusic.png",actions:[{name:"apple",type:"applemusicplay",id:"1649563461"},{name:"apple",type:"uri",uri:"https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview112/v4/bc/5c/5c/bc5c5ca1-0aa1-457d-65ce-f0f56f8a8245/mzaf_12809811648741532519.plus.aac.ep.m4a"}],options:[{caption:"OPEN",actions:[{name:"hub:applemusic:deeplink",type:"applemusicopen",uri:"https://music.apple.com/gb/album/the-astronaut/1649563458?i=1649563461&mttnagencyid=s2n&mttnsiteid=125115&mttn3pid=Apple-Shazam&mttnsub1=Shazam_web&mttnsub2=5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973&itscg=30201&app=music&itsct=Shazam_web"},{name:"hub:applemusic:deeplink",type:"uri",uri:"https://music.apple.com/gb/album/the-astronaut/1649563458?i=1649563461&mttnagencyid=s2n&mttnsiteid=125115&mttn3pid=Apple-Shazam&mttnsub1=Shazam_web&mttnsub2=5348615A-616D-3235-3830-44754D6D5973&itscg=30201&app=music&itsct=Shazam_web"}],beacondata:{type:"open",providername:"applemusic"},image:"https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/overflow-open-option.png",type:"open",listcaption:"Open in Apple Music",overflowimage:"https://images.shazam.com/static/icons/hub/web/v5/applemusic-overflow.png",colouroverflowimage:!1,providername:"applemusic"}],explicit:!1,displayname:"APPLE MUSIC"},artists:[{alias:"jin",id:"42",adamid:"1191850724"}],url:"https://www.shazam.com/track/636972694/the-astronaut",highlightsurls:{},properties:{}}];
  
  // `map` is a little neater
  const html = data.map((item, i) => {

    // Destructure the properties you need from item
    const { title, images: { background } } = item;

    // Use the index on the `post` element
    return `
      <li class="post" data-index=${i}>
        ${title}
        <img src="${background}" width="300">
      </li>
    `;

  // Make sure you join up the array that `map` returns
  // into a single HTML string
  }).join('');

  // Add the HTML to the list
  list.innerHTML = html;

}

getResponse();
```

```css
.post { background-color: #efefef; }
```

```html
<ul class="list"></ul>
```